# VPN connection between two computers both masqueraded by symmetric NAT devices

Tags: networking, vpn, nat

How to establish a VPN connection between two computers both masqueraded by symmetric NAT devices without a public IP?

I suppose [ICE technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment) with [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT) or [RSIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realm-Specific_IP) protocol should be used in order to resolve the issue. Or technique like [VPN-SIP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6193/) which using temporary supernode in order to establish connection between clients directly. The solution should be truly free and scalable, in other words TeamViewer VPN, LogMeIn Hamachi VPN, et cetera - not accounting.

Comment: Re-posting the same question isn't going to change that it is off-topic.

Comment: Dear  EEAA. I have re-phrased my last question. How should I re-phrase my question in order to unhold the question?

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6488/20815

Comment: Dear EEAA in this particular question I'm not asking for a product nor asking for best product. The only reason I mentioned TeamViewer / Hamachi is for giving direction of my thinking. Would you like me to remove "TeamViewer / Hamachi" part?

Comment: Below you commented: "Dear Alan, I'm looking for a solution not a theoretical ability.", and above in your question, "The solution should be truly free and scalable...". You're looking for a product recommendation.

Comment: Yes. But it not dealing with my question been on hold.

Comment: You are looking for a solution/product recommendation. Product recommendation questions are off-topic. I'm not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: That is correct - I'm looking for a "Solution". In other words I'm looking for straight forward answer, not a theoretical ability. I know that in theory the described issue can be resolved, that's why I provided links for ICE/TURN/RSIP/VPN-SIP techniques. Now I need to know how to do this.

Comment: ...and solution requests are off-topic.

Comment: I never said not meant a product by saying solution. Sorry I'm not native speaker.

Comment: Solutions not equal to products. Solution can be done by scripting for example. Why it would be off-topic?

Comment: For the purposes of Serverfault, "product" and "solution" are the same thing. I'm going to lock this post now due to a high number of off-topic posts. If you'd like further clarification on what type of questions are on-topic here, you can read through the Help documentation (link at the top of the page) or post on meta.serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively a question on how to bypass NAT hiding.

Using ICE or TURN will expose all client real public IP addresses.  Then again so does an IPsec Site to Site VPN.

For this to be effective the middle boxes (NAT devices) on both sides would have to allow UPnP which is unlikely outside a consumer domestic setting.

In principle once both sides have used UPnP to forward ports an IPsec site to site tunnel could be established.  Alternatively, PeerVPN could do this piece using TLS instead of IPsec.  In that case only the supernode (the PeerVPN "server" would have to have UPnP enabled on the network).  Updating the PeerVPN client to accept dynamic ports would be a bit tricky though.

Scalable probably isn't the right word unless you mean scalable to more than two, ten, one hundred peers.

LogMeIn Hamachi effectively combines these things and works well enough for P2P Minecraft between NAT hidden clients and servers:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_(software)

Comment: Dear Alan, are you sure PeerVPN can do the job? On official site there is no statement on "VPN connection between two computers both masqueraded by symmetric NAT devices without a public IP" as soon as I can find.

Comment: @BBK it can't directly. You'd need to bolt TURN/ICE on top and rewrite the configs dynamically. It would be ugly.

Comment: Dear Alan, I'm looking for a solution not a theoretical ability.

Comment: @BBK then use Hamachi like I suggested :)

Comment: Dear Alan I suppose you notice my last phrase, let me repeat it here: _The solution should be truly free and scalable, in other words TeamViewer VPN, LogMeIn Hamachi VPN, et cetera - not accounting_

Comment: @BBK "- not accounting" doesn't mean that. "Truly free and scalable" is ambiguous.  Perhaps you mean to say only Free Open Source Software (FOSS) solutions are eligible as answers.  I was actually hesitant to answer given the breadth and ambiguities in your question.